# Are all Chinese citizens currently (after COVID-19 outbreak) banned from applying for Schengen visa issued by Czech Republic?

Tags: schengen, chinese-citizens, czech-republic, covid-19

Some news reports suggested Czech Republic stopped issuing visa to Chinese *citizens/nationals* and closed visa centres in China after the outbreak of the novel coronavirus.

The latter is of course understandable. But are all Chinese nationals, regardless of travel history/place of residence, affected by this?

1. https://news.expats.cz/weekly-czech-news/the-czech-republic-has-stopped-issuing-visas-to-chinese-citizens-over-coronavirus-fears/
2. https://www.radio.cz/en/section/news/coronavirus-czechs-suspend-visas-for-chinese-citizens-flight-ban-considered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can find of [official information](https://www.vfsglobal.cn/czechrepublic/China/English/index.html), the Czech Republic has suspended the processing of visa applications and issuance of visa at the embassy in Beijing and the consulates in China (Shanghai, Chengdu) and Hong Kong. It is worth to notice that this restriction affects also non-chinese residents of China, who are now also not able to apply for a visa.

Some media have indeed reported that the visa ban applies to *all* Chinese citizens, but there is no official information supporting that and I believe these reports to be mistakes. It seems very well possible for Chinese citizens who are resident outside China to get a Czech visa from the consulates at their place of residence and there seem to be no ban for residents of China to enter the Czech Republic if they are already in posession of a visa.

Unless the Czech Republic is the main destination in the Schengen area, it should also still be possible for Chinese residents to obtain a Schengen visa from other consulates and then use that visa for travel to the Czech Republic. It will probably have little impact on actual travel patterns for a single Schengen country to impose restrictions as have been done here.

Comment: It appears that this is correct. The Czech Embassy in London replied that "Visa applications are open for all citizens who require visa in order to travel to the Czech Republic".